# Apache Airflow - Google Authentication creating only super users

Tags: google-oauth, airflow

I am implementing google authentication in airflow (Version- 1.9.0). In [google_auth.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/google_auth.py#L69), airflow is creating every user as superuser

```
def is_superuser(self):
    '''Access all the things'''
    return True
```

I only want to give superuser rights to only certain team members. So, I edited the function `is_superuser()` in `GoogleUser` class as follows:

```
def is_superuser(self):
    '''Access all the things'''
    if self.user.email in ["member1@xyz.com","member2@xyz.com"]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Is there a better way to do it or airflow provides this thing out of the box? I am not able to find anything about creating users with limited rights using google OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to newer versions with RBAC, airflow is basically just handling authentication without any authorization layer. So the super user flag is it.

Rather than hardcoding it, I'd make it configurable via airflow.cfg. That way you don't have to modify your code each time you want to update the list, just update the config and restart.

So in your airflow.cfg under say.. the `[core]` block, add `super_users = member1@xyz.com,member2@xyz.com`

And then make your function

```
def is_superuser(self):
    return self.user.email in configuration.get("core", "super_users").split(",")
```